# How to group X-axis points in react C3js?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I started working on react-c3js and got stuck into some problem.

Below is my X-axis array:

```
"axis": {"x": ["4 2018", "4 2018", "5 2018", "5 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "6 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "7 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "8 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "9 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "10 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "11 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "12 2018", "1 2019", "1 2019", "1 2019"]
}
```

it is showing chart like below

[image]

all items are shown even if they are in same month

But I need to show it like
[image]

I am using below code:

```
const Chart = ({ data }) =>
  <C3Chart axis= {{
    'x': {
        type: 'category',
        categories: data.axis['x']
    }
  }} data={{ json: data.chart_data, type:'line'}} />
```

please Help.

Comment: similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770220/multiple-values-on-x-axes-with-c3js-timeseries but didn't find solution

Answer (score 0):

You need setup as `timeseries` type instead `category`
https://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html